# C++ Messagebox in Chinese

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, messagebox

---

ConsoleApplication.cpp

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
     std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
     MessageBox(0, LPTSTR("Text Here"), LPTSTR("Text Here"), MB_OK);
     std::cin.clear();
     std::cout << "Press Enter to continue" << std::endl;
     std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
     std::cin.get();
     return 0;
}
```

---

stdafx.h

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
```

---

Whenever I run the MessageBox code, it comes out in Chinese characters.
The code is above.

Comment: That LPTSTR cast just stopped the compiler from telling you that you were doing it wrong, it didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Use L"text" to generate a string literal that uses Unicode.  Or use MessageBoxA() if you insist on using ansi strings.

Comment: Tip: In Visual Studio just run your program via Ctrl+F5 to make the console window persist at the end. That's just running it normally without the debugger (but with a driver batch file that performs a `pause` at the end). I.e., you don't need all that silly `cin`-code at then. :)

Comment: @HansPassant: *"Use `L"text"` to generate a string literal that uses Unicode."* -- No, no, no. One, "Unicode" is not an encoding. UTF-16 is, for example. And `L"text"` does not mean either "Unicode" or UTF-16, but just "`wchar_t` string of implementation-defined encoding".

Comment: @DevSolar: You're just wrong. Hans is using [the appropriate terminology for Windows programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "Unicode" is not appropriate terminology when referring to an encoding, Windows or otherwise. He can qualify his statement with "when coding for Windows", but blanket as-posted, it's misleading.

Comment: If you insist on using `TCHAR`, then the correct macro to use is `TEXT()`, not `TCHAR()`.

Comment: @DevSolar MSDN and about 8 years of UTF-8 not having been invented yet unfortunately disagree; in the specific domain of Windows API development it is generally understood that "Unicode" is interchangeable with UTF-16 and that wide strings are always UTF-16. It's a painful fact, but one a Windows developer simply has to learn to live with.

Comment: @andlabs: Oh, [UTF-8 was invented in 1992](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/utf-8-history.txt). But it took about 10-12 years to become "the" encoding in Unix-land.

Comment: @andlabs: Actually, back then what they referred to as "Unicode" was the equivalent to UCS-2 (which is why we're stuck with 16-bit `wchar_t` on Windows). But that was back then. It does not hurt Windows developers to say "UTF-16" when they mean it, and it *does* hurt the unaware if the savy continue saying "Unicode" when UTF-16 is meant, or muddying the waters between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't know when UTF-8 was actually presented to the public though...

Comment: @andlabs define public. The first time was [1992](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2044) - public=ietf (the guys dealing, among other, with internet protocols). Spec stabilized in [2003](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629)

Answer (score 1):

Your `LPTSTR` type-cast is wrong.  When compiling with `UNICODE` defined, `MessageBox()` resolves to `MessageBoxW()`, and `LPTSTR` resolves to `wchar*`, so you are really doing this:

```
MessageBoxW(0, (wchar*)"Text Here", (wchar*)"Text Here", MB_OK);
```

You are telling the compiler to type-cast narrow strings *as if* they were wide strings.  The narrow string `"Text Here"` consists of bytes `54 65 78 74 20 48 65 72 65`.  When those same bytes are *interpreted as* a wide string, they produce the Chinese string `"敔瑸䠠牥e"`.

If you are going to use `TCHAR`-based APIs, like `MessageBox()`, you need to use the [`TEXT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074.aspx) macro when passing char/string literals to them at compile-time, eg:

```
MessageBox(0, TEXT("Text Here"), TEXT("Text Here"), MB_OK);
```

When `UNICODE` is defined, `TEXT()` compiles a literal as wide.  When `UNICODE` is not defined, `TEXT()` compiles a literal as narrow.

Otherwise, do not rely on `TCHAR`-based APIs at all.  Use Ansi/Unicode versions explicitly, eg:

```
MessageBoxA(0, "Text Here", "Text Here", MB_OK);
```

```
MessageBoxW(0, L"Text Here", L"Text Here", MB_OK);
```

---

On a side note:  your call to `cin.ignore()` should use `std::numeric_limits` instead of hard-coding the length:

```
#include <limits>

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```